# How to pass parameter when I redirect the page in angularjs using ui router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to pass parameters via the ui-router state.go

However, I am not sure how to pass the parameters. Here are my codes

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {    
    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: '/first',
            templateUrl: 'first.html'
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: '/second',
            templateUrl: 'second.html'
        })
})

//my first.html
app.controller.('firstCtrl' ,["$scope", "$state", function($scope, $state){
    $scope.userInput <- come from user
    $scope.clickThis=function() {
        $state.go("second", $scope.userInput);
    }

}]);

//my second.html
app.controller.('secondCtrl,["$scope", "$state", function($scope, $state){
    //How do I get the parameter that is passed to here..
})
```

I can redirect the page to second.html but I can't seem to get the parameter that is passed to my secondCtrl. 
Can anyone help me about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First you have to add parameter in route.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {    
    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: '/first',
            templateUrl: 'first.html'
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: '/second/:id',
            templateUrl: 'second.html'
        })
});
```

Now add in first controller

```
app.controller.('firstCtrl' ,["$scope", "$state", function($scope, $state){
    $scope.userInput <- come from user
    $scope.clickThis=function() {
        $state.go("second", { id: $scope.userInput });
    }

}]);
```

In second controller inject $stateParams

```
//my second.html
app.controller.('secondCtrl',["$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", function($scope, $state, $stateParams){
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
})
```

Comment: How can I pass a object using above way? And in above example, it shows value of "id" in URL, obviously If I want to pass a object, I don't want to display that in URL too. So how's that possible?

Comment: Thank you for saving my life!

Comment: awesome dude.. one common mistake btw is , people doesn't keep the variable name same as in the template url...

Answer (score 6):

You could do this way in the first controller:-

```
$state.go("second", {'input' : $scope.userInput});
```

In the second controller inject [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) service.

```
app.controller('secondCtrl',["$scope", "$stateParams", function($scope, $stateParams){
    var data = $stateParams.input;
}]);
```

and register that in your state:

```
  .state('second', {
        url: '/second/:input',
        templateUrl: 'second.html'
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave Daus908 green because he indicates I need to add param in route which is what I am missing.:D  +1

Comment: @FlyingCat np. I guess i have also mentioned it in this answer. However the other answer came in 6 seconds before mine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding additional param in the url, you could do it on the other way.

```
.state('second', {
    url: '/second',
    templateUrl: 'second.html',
    params: {input:null}

})
```

All other changes would be same with what other answers.