# AngularJS UI router redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am trying to redirect to another page using angular redirect. But I am getting a couldn't resolve from state error. I followed the [How to pass parameter when I redirect the page in angularjs using ui router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298533/how-to-pass-parameter-when-i-redirect-the-page-in-angularjs-using-ui-router) link.

Please find below my route.js code:

```
var helloWorldApp = angular.module('helloWorldApp', ['ui.router']);
helloWorldApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('first', {
    url: '/first',
    templateUrl: 'first.html'
})

.state('second', {
    url: '/second',
    templateUrl: 'second.html'
});
});
```

My first.html code

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="helloWorldApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app/routes.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var helloAppConf = angular.module('helloWorldApp', ['ui.router']);
helloAppConf.controller('firstCtrl',function($scope,$state){
    $scope.userInput='Hello world from first page';
    $scope.getNewPage=function() {
        $state.go("second", { id: $scope.userInput });
    }
});

</script>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        <h4>{{userInput}}</h4>
        <button ng-click="getNewPage()">New Page</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My second.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="helloWorldApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/routes.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var helloAppConf = angular.module('helloWorldApp', ['ui.router']);
        helloAppConf.controller('secondCtrl' , function($scope, $state){
        $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
    });
</script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <h4>{{id}}</h4>
    <button ng-click="getNewPage()">New Page</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using springboot and my project structure snapshot is attached here:
[image: Project Structure]

I am able to access both first.html and second.html pages on my browser. But when I click on the New Page button on first.html, I get the 
Error: Could not resolve 'second' from state ''
    at Object.t.transitionTo (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:8834)
    at Object.t.go (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:8182)
    at Scope.$scope.getNewPage (http://localhost:8080/first.html:18:16)
    at fn (eval at  (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:13322:15), :4:221)
    at callback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:23549:17)
    at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:15989:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:16089:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:23554:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:3298:21)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why two html pages? 
You should have one index.html file and manage it states with <ui-view>.
So I'm not sure what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

In your second html code you inject `$state` wrongly instead of `$stateParams`. So that your code didn't work

Inject with `$stateParams`

```
var helloAppConf = angular.module('helloWorldApp', ['ui.router']);
    helloAppConf.controller('secondCtrl' , function($scope, $stateParams){
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
});
```

or use `$state.params.id`

```
var helloAppConf = angular.module('helloWorldApp', ['ui.router']);
    helloAppConf.controller('secondCtrl' , function($scope, $state){
    $scope.id = $state.params.id;
});
```

Comment: I tried both your suggestions. They didn't work. I am beginning to think if its a path issue and my JS is not able to find the html templates? Do I have to add additional tags or define them as ng-templates in my html so that routes.js can see it?