# how to perform server side redirection when using angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 4 for a web application and i wanted to know that if a post request is made in angular js to the controller can we use request dispatcher in the same controller  to forward request and response  to another page because currently I am not able to forward the request and response to another jsp page .Is there any other alternative to do server side redirection when using angular js where i can forward my request and response objects to another jsp page.
Is there any way to forward a request object to angular js along with a json object basically a method to forward the parameter values of request object to angular js?

Comment: could you give a concrete example (with code) of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to redirect in Spring using UriComponentsBuilder Class.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/RequestMappingUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ResponseEntity<> redirectExample(){
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            UriComponentsBuilder b = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/redirectURL");

             UriComponents uriComponents =  b.build();
             return new ResponseEntity<void>(headers,HttpStatus.FOUND);


        }
```

In AngularJS, ng-route can be used to display the template corresponding to the url. Otherwise, you can determine which page to display from Spring MVC Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/redirectURL",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getFaultAndRejectedMessagesPage() {
         return "htmlPageToDisplay";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to redirect post request with http redirect

Use this code.

```
public void sampleAction(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    response.sendRedirect("/someController/somePage"); 
}
```

And, [link to documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String))

Comment: But using response.sendRedirect  I cannot forward my request object to the next page .

Comment: I tried using response.send redirect but it works only when i am not expecting a response back in my angular js

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `angular.js`.Just catch responce and redirect it usiing [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service

Or you can use factory service store the data then retrieve it on required page.

if you are using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298533/how-to-pass-parameter-when-i-redirect-the-page-in-angularjs-using-ui-router)

Comment: If angular js is expecting a response from the controller can i still let the server redirect to another page without giving any response to the angular page.

Comment: Yes you can do.but angular used for SPA so try redirect it using angular

Comment: But how can i  forward a request  object from server to angular js page since it only can receive strings.